# posts_per_page doesnt work

Tags: posts, wp-query, query, cache

Here is the my custom query ;

```
            <?php
                $Poz = new WP_Query(array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'no_found_rows' => true,
                    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
                    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
                ));
            // The Query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $Poz );

            // The Loop
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?> yazısını oku."><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I start trying to minimize my queries. Found some articles about this. This method mean making just two queries.

You can check it [here](http://codewithwp.com/tutorials/optimize-wordpress-queries/) also.

The question is about posts_per_page arg. Why it doesnt work ? I think its about

```
'no_found_rows' => true,
```

this arg. That mean is no pagination for querie. But how we can limit post number ? or what we can use instead of posts per page in this query. Let talk about this.

-- Updated --

I Changed the querie method query_posts instead of new WP_Query;

```
<?php

# Cached Wordpress queries
# SE Disq : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70424/posts-per-page-doesnt-work/70425

    $Poz = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
    );

    query_posts( $Poz ); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?> yazısını oku."><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php  endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, use `'nopaging' => true`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

```
$Poz = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 3, 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
    'nopaging' => true, 
); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $Poz );
```

Comment: `'nopaging' => true` is the same ? is this making more query or not ? Also i add that line to but the results actually posts number display like main query

Comment: `nopaging` tells WordPress: look dude, I know you're paging by default, but stop this and just give me my X posts. So, less query, I suppose.

Comment: I confused but it doesnt work also. :/

`<?php
     $Poz = new WP_Query(array(
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'no_found_rows' => true,
      'update_post_term_cache' => false,
      'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
      'nopaging' => true,
     ));
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $Poz );

    // The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?> yazısını oku."><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`

Comment: Wait a sec. this is not the reason. I totally missed it. this should be: `$Poz = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'no_found_rows' => true,
                    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
                    'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 'nopaging' => true, 
                );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $Poz );` The `$Poz` should be args for the new WP_Query

Comment: try it please doesnt work. All posts came (: The query doesnt care with numbers.

Comment: It's not about `'no_found_rows' => true,` it's about passing the arguments to `new WP_Query`

Comment: Should we change query method ? like using get_posts(); or something instead of `new Query` ?

Comment: It's up to you. I'd use WP_Query. The point is that `$Poz` is supposed to be arguments for the query, not a new query.

Comment: Now i got it i think. Here is the new code : https://gist.github.com/3951155 But you should know when you add no-pagging parameter it doesnt work again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6233/discussion-between-fatih-toprak-and-daniel-sachs)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I use WP Query inside a [posts] shortcode made by me. "posts_per_page" and "nopaging" attributes are passed as shortcode attributes (everything is working here) but it returns me ALL posts.

Comment: SOLVED! The problem was I had some sticky posts. So the working query for me has 'posts_per_page'=>3 and 'ignore_sticky_posts'=>true.